# How to accumulate a score/value based on the choices selected on a form using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I wanna to try to researching around on how to achieve this but I am not sure about how to make the solution for this.

Basically I have a form that contains some select list, radio buttons, and checkboxes. Each option on the form has a corresponding numeric value that will be accumulated and displayed to the user when the form gets submitted.

What I am not sure about is how to be able to add or deduct a value if the user chooses to change the a choice on the form.

For example, when a user is on the first dropdown element, and they choose option 2 which has a value of 5 then the current accummulated value us 5. Then on question 2, they choose option 1 which has a value of 2 which makes the accummulated value 7. Then the user changes the answer for question one from option 2 to option one which means 5 will be deducted from the accumulated value and 2 will be added since it is the value for option 1 which changes the accumulated value to 4.

I know the description I mentioned might be all over the place but I hope it makes sense.

I am trying to use jQuery and so far, my approach would be to check if any of the form element's value has changed:

```
(function($) {
    var score = 0;
    $(".the-form #step-5 :input").change(function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
})(jQuery);
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to get the previous value of the option that was selected if the user changes their answer.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't add up the score untill the user clicks submit. If it's a form you would would add an event listener for the submit event. In jQuery this looks like: `$( ".the-form" ).submit(function( event ) { })` and in Javascript it could look like this: `form.onsubmit = function( event ) { }` or `form.addEventListener('submit', function( event ) { })`. In JS get the element with something like `var form = document.querySelector(".the-form")`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you recalculate across the whole form each time the user changes any of the elements?

```
$(".the-form :input").change(calculateChanges);

function calculateChanges() {
    // Retrieve the current values of all elements and add them together
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a user submits, then start doing the calculations or when a select is changed, i.e. attach it to the event. Score is now a local variable

```
function calcValue() {
    var score = 0;

   //select all the elements using example below
   $(".the-form :input").each(function( index ) {
     //i forgot jQuery exact syntax but $(this).val or //$(this).val()  
      score += $( this ).val();
   });
   console.log(score);
}
```

In this case you can attach it to the submit

```
function submit() {
    var score = calcValue();
}
```

Or you can put it in a change event of a select

```
function selectChanged() {
    var score = calcValue();
}
```